# How do you include a dot in a "as" statement in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
SELECT
    metadata.field as something.field
FROM
    tbl2
```

This query does not work because of the period in the "as" statement.  If I remove it, the query will work fine.  I cannot encapsulate something.field in quotes and I cannot seem to escape the dot.  Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: Enclose in square brackets [something.field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks (``) as in the following example:

```
create table papo1 as select date as `pi.po` from t1 ;
hive> describe papo1;
OK
pi.po                   string
```